# Making Stripe User Checkout Email as {{ request.user.email }} in Django project

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, stripe-payments

Hi Djangonauts,
                   I am integrating stripe in my in my project. I do not want users to enter their email in their stripe payment form. Instead I want the email they registered on my site as their checkout email. I have the below form. When this form renders. It asks for users.

Name:, 
Email:, 
Billing Address:, 
Credit Card Details:,

Can I change email from

```
email = request.POST['stripeEmail']
```

to

```
If user.is_authenticated:
     email = request.user.email
```

I am aware that by doing this anonymous users will not be able to checkout and I am ok with that. I can add `@loginrequired()` decorator before the function

I have Order history view

```
@login_required()
def orderHistory(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        email = str(request.user.email)
        order_details = Order.objects.filter(emailAddress=email)        
    return render(request, 'order/order_list.html', {'order_details': order_details})
```

This code fetches Orders in Order History `order_details = Order.objects.filter(emailAddress=email)` when users sign up with 1 email and use another email at checkout the orders don't appear in their Order history. Plus it is mandatory to have a account to checkout that's why I needed the below

Below are the **views.py** of my shopping cart

```
def cart_detail(request, total=0, counter=0, cart_items=None):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, active=True)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.tasting.price * cart_item.quantity)
            counter += cart_item.quantity
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    stripe_total = int(total * 100)
    description = 'Khal: Share your recipes - New tasting request'
    data_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # print(request.POST)
        try:
            token = request.POST['stripeToken']
            email = request.POST['stripeEmail']
            billingName = request.POST['stripeBillingName']
            billingAddress1 = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressLine1']
            billingCity = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressCity']
            billingZipcode = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressZip']
            billingCountry = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressCountryCode']
            customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                email=email,
                source=token
            )
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=stripe_total,
                currency='usd',
                description=description,
                customer=customer.id,
            )
            '''Creating the Order'''
            try:
                order_details = Order.objects.create(
                    token=token,
                    total=total,
                    emailAddress=email,
                    billingName=billingName,
                    billingAddress1=billingAddress1,
                    billingCity=billingCity,
                    billingZipcode=billingZipcode,
                    billingCountry=billingCountry,

                )
                order_details.save()
                for order_item in cart_items:
                    oi = OrderItem.objects.create(
                        tasting=order_item.tasting.post.title,
                        quantity=order_item.quantity,
                        price=order_item.tasting.price,
                        order=order_details
                    )
                    oi.save()
                    '''Reduce stock when Order is placed or saved'''
                    tastings = Tasting.objects.get(id=order_item.tasting.id)
                    tastings.stock = int(order_item.tasting.stock - order_item.quantity)
                    tastings.save()
                    order_item.delete()
                    '''The terminal will print this message when the order is saved'''
                    print('The order has been created')
                    try:
                        '''*********************Calling the sendEmail function************************************'''
                        sendEmail(order_details.id)
                        print('The order email has been sent to the customer.')
                    except IOError as e:
                        return e
                return redirect('order:thanks', order_details.id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            return False,e
    return render(request, 'cart/cart.html', dict(cart_items=cart_items, total=total, counter=counter, data_key=data_key,
                                             stripe_total=stripe_total, description=description))
```

I have also attached below my **cart.html template**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{{ data_key }}"
    data-amount="{{ stripe_total }}"
    data-name="Perfect Cushion Store"
    data-description="{{ description }}"
    data-image="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="usd"
    data-shipping-address="true"
    data-billing-address="true"
    data-zip-code="true">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see why you can't just keep in mind to give a stripe token to the authentified user's email so he can pay.

Comment: @NuriKatsuki I have added my Order history view in the question. That was the reason I wanted to make these changes

Comment: Your question is too broad, you're asking if you can change 'stripeEmail' by another one, in which the answer is yes. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @NuriKatsuki Sorry dint know if `email` was a required field in stripe forms. and if stripe insisted that the user type their own email. I just want email to be a prepopulated field with the email of the user that is registered on my website. This will help me link orders to users profiles. See Order history code above. If not I stand the risk of users entering different emails from the one they used to register on my site. In which case the orders will not show in their profiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can hide email by including `data-email` into the stripe script :

**cart.html:**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <script ... data-email="{{request.user.email}}"></script>
</form>
```

You could then retrieve `stripeEmail` or directly use `request.user.email` in your view.